# Unsure why variable is undefined. Possible scope issue?

Tags: javascript

If you look at the function below, on line 11 where it `alert(template);`. It prints `undefined`. If I `alert(template);` inside the ajax success callback, it prints no problem. Since template is defined at the top of the function, shouldn't this be global through out the entire function? Can someone assist me with this?

```
function load_template(path, data, callback){
    var template;

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        success: function(uncompiled_template){
            template = Handlebars.compile(uncompiled_template);
        }
    });

    alert(template);    

    if(callback){
        callback(template, data);
    }else{
        return template(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not a scope issue, it's a timing issue.

The AJAX call is asynchronous, so the success callback runs later, when the response arrives. The variable is simply not set yet, when you try to use it.

You can't return the value from the function, as the success callback never runs until you have exited the function. Always use the callback that is sent to the function:

```
function load_template(path, data, callback){

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        success: function(uncompiled_template){
            var template = Handlebars.compile(uncompiled_template);
            callback(template, data);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. How would I go about returning the template variable from the load_template function. Advice?

Comment: @Kylee: If you absolutely need to return the value, you can make a synchronous AJAX call instead (using `async: false` in the settings). That will however freeze the entire browser while it's waiting for the response.

Comment: Ok. Not the best solution for loading and rendering templates then. Thanks for the follow up answer.

Answer (score 1):

ajax is asynchronous. to explain in simple terms: ajax *works like* it runs on a separate "thread", processing in the background while your code continues.

by the time you called `load_template()`, it alerts after `$.ajax()` was called **but before the template was returned** thus `undefined`.

what you can do is this so everything runs after a success has been returned:

```
function load_template(path, data, callback){

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        success: function(uncompiled_template){
            var template = Handlebars.compile(uncompiled_template);

            alert(template);    

            if(callback){
                callback(template, data);
            }else{
                return template(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

template isnt defined until your ajax request is completed.

thats why it shows fine in the success function.

not sure what framework that is ( JQuery I presume ) but you need to do the callback in the ajax success function.

Answer (score 0):

The `success` function *is* a callback. The javascript engine makes the request to the server, and when the server responds to the data, *then* it runs the `success` function and you have the data, so the `success` function is run *after* your if statement at the end, even though its defined beforehand.

Javascript code is run inside of an [Event Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop), all `$.ajax` is doing is starting an asynchronous event and specifying what to do when that event occurs.